# How to get the date every time a day passes in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, nodemailer

What I intend to do is a program that sends congratulatory emails for their birthday to several users, then the program will take today and execute a query to the database (it is an Excel file), in which it will take the date of the users and compare their date of birth with the current date, if the month and day coincide, mail will be sent. I think it can be done with a `setInterval()`, but I don't know if it affects the performance of the program. Since it will be uploaded on a windows server 2012 server of my company.

My code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const excel = require('./public/scripts/readExcel.js');
const email = require('./services/email/sendEmail.js');
     
app.post('/send-email',(req, res)=>{
  setInterval(() => {
    email.sendEmail()
    .then((result) => {
        res.status(200).jsonp(req.body);;
        console.log(result)
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).jsonp(req.body);;
        console.log(err);
    });
  }, 3600000);//1 hour
    
});
app.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log("Serven on -> http://localhost:4000");
})
```

Basically what it does is call the `sendEmail` function every hour which reads the Excel file or the database and extracts the date fields, compares with the current day, and sends the mail with Nodemailer to those who have birthdays. Also, the `setInterval` would go in the route of "/send-email" or how would the request be made?

Comment: Did you try cronJobs?

Comment: @Mohammednaji No

Comment: then you need to try the cronJobs and you must understand it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you can also run a cron job at every hour using npm package [cron-job](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)
using

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * 1 * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every hour');
});
```

Comment: And how would the request to the "/send-mail" route be made when deploying the application?

Comment: In your case, you don't have to call the route every hour. Just make a function where you check birthdays from excel for today and then send mail if the user has a birthday. and put that function into the cron-job.No need to call url

Comment: So instead of using the route I use the cron, and inside this I put the function that sends the emails?

Comment: A little off-topic, but might help you here. Take a look at clean architecture if you need to accomodate both an express application and a cron jobs. Probably with the right architecture you will be able to reuse all the business logic and write an adapter for the cron jobs and an adapter for the express app endpoint (if required)

Answer (score 1):

I'll break down my answer in two parts

1. What you need to do to **make your solution work**
2. How can you **optimise the performance**

**1. What you need to do to make your solution work**

There are two essential problems you need to resolve.

a. Your solution will work as it is, only thing you need to do is to call `/send-email` endpoint once after starting your server. **BUT...** this comes with side effects.
As setInterval will call the `email.sendEmail...` code block every hour, and this code block calls `res.status(200).jsonp(req.body)` every time. If you don't know this `res.status..` sets the response for the request you receive. In this case, your request to `/send-email`. For the first time, it will work fine because you are returning the response to your above request. But when second time call to this code block kicks in, it has nothing to respond to because request has already been responded. Remember, HTTP protocol responds to a request once, then the request has been completed. So for this reason, your code block `res.status...` becomes invalid. So first thing, call `res.status` only once. So I'd remove this line out of the setInterval code block as follows

```
app.post('/send-email',(req, res)=>{
  setInterval(() => {
    email.sendEmail()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }, 3600000);//1 hour
  res.status(200).jsonp(req.body);
})
```

b. Also I don't think you'd want the hastle of calling `/send-email` every time you start server, so I'd also make sure that this code block for birthday wishes gets kicked off every time you start server automatically. So I'd then just remove the line `app.post('/send-email',(req, res)=>{`. Also not that I'm not calling this for a request, I don't have any request to send response to so I can also remove the `res.status..` line. And your code looks like this now

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const email = require('./services/email/sendEmail.js');

(function(){ 
  // Birthday wish email functionality
  setInterval(() => {
    email.sendEmail()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }, 3600000);//1 hour
})() // Immediately invoked function
```

That's it, your solution works now. Now to send birthday wish emails, you don't need to do anything else other than just starting your server.

---

Let's move on to second part now

**2. How can you optimise the performance**

a. Set interval to be 24hrs instead of 1 hr

Why do you need to check every hour for birthday? If you don't have a good answer here, I'd definitely change the interval to be 24hrs

b. Making the code more robust to deal with large data

As long as you have only 100s of entries in your excels and they are not going to grow much in future, I wouldn't go into making it more complex for performance.
But if your entries are destined to grow to 1000s and further. I'd suggest to use database(such as mongodb, postgres or mysql, etc.) to store your data and query only the entries with the birthday matching the particular date.
I'd also implement a queuing system to process query and send emails in batches instead of doing all of that at once.